Main panel busbar rating older square D- pertaining to solar install
This is my first post here, so please bear with me! I have been researching and planning a partial DIY solar install. I am planning a ~10kw array with a hybrid inverter (EG4 12kpv). I have attempted to determine some specs on my main service panel, this is a VERY old house with lots of work done before I moved in.
I opened the panel and looked for label to indicate. There are several labels, and I will attach the pictures. QO MG200 series E5 appears to be it. From that I can gather 200A and much of what I've read suggests if its not explicitly said that typically busbar will be the same (i.e 200A). I tried looking on the manufacturer's website, scrolled through numerous forums. My question pertains to the 120% rule.
I will be submitting my info to a service that creates permitting and designs for you from the info you provide them, and will have electrician to do actual wiring but I would like to be as thorough as possible. I have also been reading the EG4 wiring EG4 12kpv wiring diagrams. Page 3 Backfed breaker.
The annotations say the panel can be derated, or the inverter can be derated.
Just to clarify, no battery backup planned during initial install. Ideally just get basic PV and inverter installed to code, if possible get net metering with my utility. For brief outages generac generator. In the future perhaps I will add on battery backup. If there is further information I can provide to clarify I will happily do so. Thank you all so much and I hope my writing is coherent as I am very sleep deprived currently!
Cheers and warm regards!



Is this location inside some sort of porch space or the like, or actually outdoors? Also, I take it there's a transfer switch between your meter and your "main" panel?

This location in inside. Its in a closet inside what once was a porch but is now more of a "mud room". Yes, I was going to upload additional pictures of the outside showing the meter etc but didnt do that initially for brevity sake. I can upload those pictures if its helpful.

When you install a battery and/or V2X system, a new piece of hardware will need to be installed called a MID, which goes between "the meter" and "all your breakers you want on battery backup including your solar".
In your installation, that will probably go between the meter and the main breaker.

My question pertains to the 120% rule.

I knew it!
The 120% rule is only a problem for solar installers who follow "paint by numbers" recipe books and don't actually understand the underlying material.
The 120% rule ONLY applies in one edge case.  You have a single bus (or connected buses without a breaker between them) where a) the sum of circuit breakers for available supplies exceeds the bus rating, and b) the sum of load circuit breakers exceeds the bus rating.  In this edge cases, the supplies and loads could conspire to put more load on the bus than it can handle.  So... don't create that situation and you won't have to worry about the 120% rule.
This usually arises when people slap the solar breaker inside the main panel because they're coloring by numbers. Don't.
Is solar even required to be on your side of the main breaker?  No it's not - see NEC 230.82.  You can simply
take a "service side tap" on the service side of the main breaker, go to a small panel, and put the solar breakers in that panel. They make vampire taps for service wires for that purpose.
Or, come off the meter (leaving space for a MID) to a "trailer/ranch panel", then off the "thru lugs" of the ranch panel to feed the main breaker in the existing panel.  The ranch panel constitutes an "island between main breakers" which can accommodate up to 200A of solar.

Now I'm seeing an indoor panel, doorbell transformer, NM-B cable, siding like outdoors, and a masking tape label that isn't rain-destroyed.  Tell me this location is actually indoors, because the first 3 things I listed are not allowed outdoors.

Thank you for the reply! Yes I only asked about the 120 rule as I hear those type of "paint by numbers" configurations referenced often. The EG4 wiring diagram I referenced showed several possible setups, one of which seemed similar to what you described. Feeder tap, supply side tap, and backfed (the paint by numbers ;) ).

The setup is inside in my mudroom in a closet. The mudroom was previously a porch a long time ago. Its a very old house from 1890s. Built in stages. Definitely not outside!
